# How old is Mr Peanutbutter?

Tags: bojack-horseman

The [*BoJack Hoseman* wiki](https://bojackhorseman.fandom.com/wiki/Mr._Peanutbutter) lists Mr Peanutbutter's birthday as August 20, 1969.

But [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Peanutbutter) is lists it as August 20, 1968.

I'm wondering how this information was gotten? Was it ever mentioned in the show? I get I probably shouldn't trust wikipedia or this fandom wiki. But I'd like to know if it was ever mentioned in the show.

Comment: I'm not sure is it stated outright, but I think that Mr Peanutbutter said that he is 5 years younger than Bojack. who was born in 1964, which would make  born on **1969**.

Comment: @Yasskier Not necessarily. BoJack is born on January 2, 1964, so somebody who was born on August 20, 1968 is 4 years, 7 months, 18 days younger. Which they might round to "five years".

Comment: @Yasskier if you could give a citation for Bojack's date of birth and a citation for Mr Peanutbutter saying he is 5 years younger than Bojack I think that would be a great answer. If not I can try to find those sources. I think I already found the source for Bojack's date of birth being January 2nd 1964